# Force element to fit between top of last sibling and bottom of page with scroll overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an element which goes past the bottom of the page. I want to force it to end at the bottom of the page and have a scroll (both vertical and horizontal) in the element wrapper (the element is a table and the wrapper has an ID of "table-wrapper" in the sample HTML). Likewise, I've seen many similar questions, but none of the answers helped (I've tried flex box, setting height of body and HTML, absolute and relative positions, but nothing seems to work). The only idea I currently have is using a resize observer on the last sibling and an intersection observer and setting the height and width for the element every time (only setting height to some amount seems to be working to keep it from going past the bottom, but I can't know that in advance), but I'm hoping for a more css-oriented approach. Sample HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>A</title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-size:30px;">
    <div class="control-container">
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Asdsd</span>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>asd</li>
          <li>sds</li>
          <li>dsads</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>SAdsads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-wrapper" style="overflow:scroll;">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
          <th>6</th>
          <th>7</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>SADSd</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```